# Pronunciation of 清音 and 濁音

Tags: readings

橋 reads as はし but 新橋 reads as しんばし

澤 as さわ and 金澤 as かなざわ etc.

any rules for how to pronounce?

Comment: これは読まれましたか。https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rendaku